# UK spouse 5-year route without settlement

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

My wife is at the end of her second 2.5 year spousal visa. We have the option to apply for settlement under the 5-year route. We are only planning to stay in the UK for another 2 years. Can we apply for another 2.5 year spousal visa instead of settlement (it's about £800 cheaper)?